# How to get facebook oauth token using python?

Tags: python, django, facebook, oauth

I want to get access token from facebook. I am using facepy library. I have posted snippets below.

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'face',
    'facepy',
)

 FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_INITIAL_PERMISSIONS = ['publish_actions', 'publish_stream', 'manage_pages']
```

**this is my urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'face.views.authorize_application', name='authorize_application'),
    url(r'^rag_the_app/$', 'face.views.get_token', name='get_token'),
    url(r'^oauth/access_token/$', 'face.views.manage_pages', name='manage_pages'),
    )
```

**this is my views.py**

```
import urllib
from facepy import GraphAPI
from facepy.utils import get_extended_access_token


def authorize_application(request):

    query = {
        'client_id': FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID,
        'redirect_uri': 'http://%s:8000/%s' % (FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_DOMAIN, FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_NAMESPACE),
        'scope': FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_INITIAL_PERMISSIONS

    }
    return render(
        request = request,
        template_name = 'authorization.html',
        dictionary = {
            'url': 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?%s' % urllib.urlencode(query)
        },
        status = 401
    )



def get_token(request):

    code = request.GET.get('code', '')

    query = {
        'client_id': FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID,
        'redirect_uri': 'http://%s:8000/%s' % (FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_DOMAIN, FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_NAMESPACE),
        'client_secret': FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_SECRET_KEY,
        'code': code
        }

    return render(
        request = request,
        template_name = 'authorization.html',
        dictionary = {
            'url': 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?%s' % urllib.urlencode(query)
            }, 
        )
    request.session['access_token'] = response['access_token']


def manage_pages(request):

    oauth_access_token = get_extended_access_token(access_token, FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID, FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_SECRET_KEY)
    graph = GrahAPI(oauth_access_token)
    page_id = '263880043816054'
    og_path = "%d/feed" %page_id
    graph.post( path = og_path, message = "hello page" )
```

**Facebook App basic setting**

```
canvas url: http://localhost:8000 
secure canvas url: https://localhost:8000
app_domain: localhost:8000
```

**Facebook App advanced settings**

Valid OAuth redirect URIs

```
http://localhost:8000/oauth/access_token/
```

**When I run my server, it raises an error**

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

How can I get the access token?
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your dev server to the Internet and give Facebook a way of reaching you for that callback. You can't use localhost.

All of:

- Canvas URL
- Secure Canvas URL
- Valid OAuth redirect URIs

...should be the domain/URL of your server, as reachable to the Internets.

Comment: why i cant use my localhost for redirect uri

Comment: because "localhost" universally means "this machine". So when you set those values to "localhost", the facebook server that will process the oauth flow will attempt to redirect to localhost (which, from its perspective, is itself), so you wouldn't get the callback with the token delivered to your server. The flow is (more or less) `[Your Server:User click Log In With Facebook]->[Facebook:User approves or not]->[Your Server:Callback from Facebook with approval/rejection]`. Facebook has to be able to reach you in order to give you the callback with the token (or rejection).

Comment: so if i wanted to test my app locally how i can do it?

Comment: If you really have to, I *think* you can force the redirect by creating an `/etc/hosts` entry on the machine you will be browsing from, with something like `127.0.0.1 somedoma.in`. Then set your redirect URLs to http://somedoma.in/. FB should then return the flow to your local machine. I am not 100% sure about this, though.